# how can I send user's information to user account view in the sails.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, sails.js, sails-mongo

I disable blueprints rooting  ( actions: false, rest: false, shortcuts: false )
and i want when a user login i can capte user's information in the "account" view, i use mongodb database and sails-mongo as adapter

UserController.js

```
  account : function (req, res, next) {
     User.findOne(req.param('id'), function foundUser(err, user){
        if (err) return next(err);
        if (!user) return next();
        res.view({
            user: user
        });
    });
},
login: function (req, res) {

    // See `api/responses/login.js`
    return res.login({
        email: req.param('email'),
        password: req.param('password'),
        successRedirect: '/user/account/' + user.id ,
        invalidRedirect: '/user/login'
    });
},
```

account.ejs

```
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h1 class="page-header">
           <%= user.firstname +' '+ user.lastname %></h1>
            <ol class="breadcrumb">
                <li class="active">
                    <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Dashboard
                </li>
            </ol>
        </div>
```

routes.js

```
 'get /user/login': { view: 'User/login' },
'get /user/signup': { view: 'User/signup' },
'/user/account/:id': { view: 'User/account' },
'post /user/login': 'UserController.login',
'post /user/signup': 'UserController.signup',
'/user/logout': 'UserController.logout',
'user/account/:id': 'UserController.account'
```

after login i want to fetch name, email of the user by id to use it in the view like this

```
                <a class="text-center" href="#">
                    <strong>Welcome <%= user.firstname %></strong>
                    <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                </a>
```

how can i do it, thanks.

Comment: isn't it req.param.id ? Also, if you do it like this anybody can see anybody account info. You have to get the id from the logged in user

Comment: @yBrodsky you are right, but it don't work with req.param.id i can't fetched other info from user, thanks for ur comment.

Comment: @SofienAbdeddaim can you say a bit more about what the steps are to reproduce your problem, what you're expecting to happen, and what's going wrong?  Just asking "what am I doing wrong" is a bit too broad of a question.

Comment: @sgress454 thanks for your comment, i modify the question, thank you.

Comment: Could you please post the code of `api/responses/login.js` ?

Comment: @mandeep_m91 i don't have api/responses/login.js, just i have login in userController.